# Defining good faith

Tags: united-states, property, statutes

“‘Good faith’ means **honesty in fact in the conduct or transaction concerned**.” OCGA §11-1-201(19).

“‘Good faith’ in the case of a merchant means **honesty in fact** and the observance of reasonable commercial standards of fair dealing in the trade.” OCGA §11-2-103(1)(b).

Above are two statutes defining good faith. Good faith is required to be a good faith purchaser. A purchaser must be a good faith purchaser in order to qualify as a Bona Fide Purchaser (BFP).

Please tell me what the bolded parts mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"honesty in fact" means not making false statements of fact, in short not lying about the facts. And as a comment calls to my mind, it also means not engaging in deception by ommission. That is it means not failing to state relevant and material facts about the transaction.

A "good faith purchaser" is one who bought not as part of a scheme or with any deceptive intent. It is one who bought at a fair price or what s/he believed to be a fair price.  It is one who bought because s/he desired to own the property. It is not, for example, one who bought at an unfairly low price, using some improper advantage, or extorting a low price, or concealing inside information. It is not one who bought on behalf of another who could not afford to appear in the transaction.

Comment: In some contexts, doesn't it also imply **not** leaving out important facts with deceptive intent?   It would seem like that would include the seller in a transaction as well.

Comment: @Burt_Harris Quite true, and I ahvbe added tht to my answer..

Comment: Did you mean *commission* or *omission*?

Comment: @Ben Voigt Thank you, that was an error, I meant omission.